# Reading numpy ndarrays into R?

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, rcpp

I've got a numpy `ndarray` in three dimensions, saved to disk as a `.npy` file.  I want to bring it into R to apply some statistical functions that aren't implemented in python.  Is there a convenient way to do so?  The [RcppCNPy](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.cnpy.html) doesn't generalize to 3+ dimensions, at least not yet.

I could always save the array in some different format on the python side, but that'd be less convenient and more error-prone.

Here's some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
goats_are_super = np.array(list(range(24))).reshape(4,3,2)
np.save("goats_are_super", goats_are_super)
```

Comment: Can you upload the `.npy` file or a dummy file for us to test? It is also possible to use `reticulate` to import your file. Perhaps this will work: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppCNPy/vignettes/UsingReticulate.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use [reticulate](https://cran.r-project.org/package=reticulate) to wrap from R around the existing Python code.  This is a little newer, but pretty general supporting many types.

In the [RcppCNPy](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppCNPy) package I have [vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppCNPy/vignettes/UsingReticulate.pdf) showing how [reticulate](https://cran.r-project.org/package=reticulate) can do what [RcppCNPy](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppCNPy) does (of course at a cost of potentially slightly more involved installation) so maybe give that a try?

Again, the vignette is [here](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppCNPy/vignettes/UsingReticulate.pdf) for your perusal.

Comment: Awesome. Cudos also to @J_F who suggested it which I hadn't seen when I wrote my answer.   If you want to add a pararaph to the vignette, can you maybe sketch it and send it to me or file it as an issue at the GH repo for RcppCNPy ?

Comment: Done:  check your github.  Thanks again!

Comment: Saved me a bunch of trouble. Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2016, I had a similar issue. The solution that Avinash Balakrishnan and myself came up with can be found here:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/numpy-arrays-to-r-array-objects/

In short, we used `rpy2` to handle the conversion of NumPy to an *R* array.

```
import os, sys, getopt
import numpy as np
import re

from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri

def convert_numpy(path_to_data, fname, export_dir):
    """Convert NumPy N-D array to R object

    Keyword arguments:
    path_to_data -- full dir path to data
    fname        -- partial file name to match
    export_dir   -- Name of export dir added to data dir
    """  
    # Create a directory path
    if not os.path.exists("%s/%s" % (path_to_data,export_dir)):
        os.makedirs("%s/%s" % (path_to_data,export_dir))

    # Get list of files in the directory
    files = os.listdir(path_to_data)

    # Sort out which files are of each type
    numpy_files = sorted([f for f in files if fname in f])

    # Begin process conversion
    for numpy_fname in numpy_files:

        # Load in 4D Numpy Array
        d = np.load("%s/%s" % (path_to_data, numpy_fname))

        # Remove the file extension of .npy binary
        file_name = re.sub('\.npy$', '', numpy_fname)

        # Convert the numpy object to R
        ro = numpy2ri(d)

        # Assign the name
        r.assign("%s" % file_name,ro)

        # Export to .gzip readable by R's load() 
        r("save(%s, file='%s/%s/%s.gzip', compress=TRUE)" % (file_name,path_to_data,export_dir,file_name))
```

This can be read into *R* using:

```
load("a_patches_b1.gzip")
```

Comment: The simpler `reticulate`-based answer has now been committed  as addition to the vignette, see https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcnpy/commit/54c908dc793c933e235cb5f63b87a4c4c7f1860b

Comment: @eddelbuettel no offense, but this wasn't really in the running for that and came before `reticulate`. The `reticulate` solution is much nicer than the `rpy2` variant.

Comment: I'd delete this one.

Comment: "patches" is not found. What is it supposed to be? Also did you manage to install this on regular python 3 or only anaconda?(I'm trying to implement it in both but having trouble)

Comment: That should be switched to `d`